Is the restriction of an ergodic continuous flow to a discrete flow still ergodic?
This is probably a very standard result in ergodic theory, but I failed to find the answer. I am looking mostly for references.
Assume $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}, (\theta_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}})$ is an ergodic dynamical system, does it follow that $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}, (\theta_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}})$ is a discrete ergodic system?
If I had to guess, I would say this result is unlikely to be true. If $\mathcal{I}_{f}$, $\mathcal{I}_{c}$  are the respective invariant $\sigma$-algebras of the continuous and discrete flow, one has $\mathcal{I}_{c} \subset \mathcal{I}_{f}$. But the reverse inclusion is rather unlikely and I guess it is possible to build a simple counter-example.
If my intuition is correct, is there any ''natural'' conditions ensuring the discrete dynamical system is still ergodic?
